# Eagle CAD custom SMD pad for bushing contact

Tags: eaglecad, surface-mount

I want to attach a panel mount potentiometer to a PCB. But I need the bushing to be grounded. Ideally I would just make the hole for the pot thru plated but the fab does not permit really large thru plated holes. So my first attempt is two SMD pads with a thru plated hole in the middle like this:

[image: eagle bushing contact]

This obviously has issues. Can anyone recommend an alternative solution?

If not, do you think this would work if I accept all of the overlap and clearance issues with these pads? Will the hole actually be through plated so that the top and bottom pads are in fact connected?

UPDATE 1:

As suggested by Peter Bennett, a possible solution is to make a circle using the bStop layer to expose the ground plane:

[image: eagle bStop for bushing contact]

So there would be no contact on top but I think because the tin is slightly raised and soft it should make good contact with the bushing. We'll see ...

Comment: Is that a via or a through-hole pad? If the latter, try adding it as a via in the layout rather than a hole in the footprint. Also, refer to this [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252355/how-to-connect-same-signal-pads-in-package-editor-in-eagle/252361#252361) for connecting the pads.

Comment: Thanks. Append does help a lot with the schematic. But I have to manually create two vias (one from bottom to top and one from top to bottom) to resolve all routing and DRC errors. I would be fabulous if there were a more streamlined solution.

Comment: It looks like you have a ground plane around the hole, so just creating a larger "hole" in the solder mask should allow a good connection between the pot bushing and ground.  No need for an explicit pad or via.

Comment: Mmmn, that is kind of brilliant. How do I create a hole in the solder mask. What layer means "don't put solder mask here"?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that the potentiometer's nut will make a reliable contact with the small pad like that.  To make a reliable contact, I would make the pad encircle the hole completely, and put a *star washer* between the pad and the nut.  Alternatively, do that on the bottom layer.

Comment: The pads encompass more than 45 degrees and the pads are on both sides so at least one tooth of the washer should make contact. But I agree it is not ideal. If there is a way to make a circular "pad" with a hole in it, I'm v. interested.