# How to create device variant with different pin count in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, footprint, device

I have a part that has 2 variants SOT-23-3 and SOT-23-5. Both have different schematics as one has 3 pins and other 5 pins. Package is also different due to difference in pin count.

The problem is that I can't create a device variant as the pin count is different. I also tried simply creating a second device but then I end up with invalid part name as device names have to be unique and variant name is appended to the device name.

What is the proper way of creating such a part?

Here is a datasheet for the part: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2210.pdf

Comment: If they are so different that one has more schematic pins that the other, create a separate part.

Comment: OP - do you mean they have same symbols but different land patterns? If so you can use a single symbol and add package variants, but if you have different symbols, then do as Tom says. Your usage of "different schematics" is a bit unclear.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/252361/61257) answer by @TomCarpenter in a previous question of mine solves your issue? 1-Create Symbol/Device; 2-Add a variant; 3-Append pads to a given net.

Comment: See edit for datasheet.

Comment: @TomCarpenter It's the same part and it refers to it as a variant in the datasheet. Creating separate part is not ideal as it only has minor differences. Why allow creating multiple symbols and packages if they cannot be used to make a device in Eagle?

Comment: The multiple variants to a part is only applicable if all the variants have the same schematic, but different packages. In your case the variants have different schematic symbols, so you **have** to make two separate parts. You actually are looking two **different** part numbers with a common datasheet - is the one AP2210K and the other AP2210N.

Comment: I assume it is normal for matching device and symbol names to be the same or is there a better convention? Also am still seeing duplicate variant name ie.: AP2210NN, it doesnt seem like I can leave it blank or at least change it to be blank.

Comment: @DominicM if you want the variant name to be blank, use `''` (two single quotes) as the name.

Comment: That was it, I was trying double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eagle you can define a part with multiple package variants, so long as they have the same schematic symbol(s).

In your case you actually are looking two different part numbers with a common datasheet, the first being the AP2210K and the second the AP2210N.

These two parts have different schematic functionality which means proper way of making such a part is in fact to make two separate parts, one for the AP2210K, and the other for the AP2210N.

Comment: The use of the word variant threw me I guess, this makes sense, thanks.